# How can I change the format for react datepicker days of the week?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using [React Datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) and all is working great.

Instead of having "Su" "Mo" "Tu" etc. for days of the week, I'd like to use something like this:

```
"Sun" "Mon" "Tue"
```

I am accomplishing this via css:

```
.react-datepicker__day-name {
    ...
    &:first-child {
        &:after {
            visibility: visible;
            position: relative;
            left: -0.5rem;
            text-align: center;
            content: "Sun";
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but also seems pretty "hacky". Is there a configuration option that I'm missing somewhere that I can specify what format(s) I'd like to use?

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Here is how I am (trying) to pass the `dateFormat` to my component:

**App.js**

```
this.state = {
    startDate: new Date(),
    dateFormat: 'ddd'
};


...

render() {
    ...
     <ReservationCalendar
         dateFormat={ this.state.dateFormat }
         startDate={ this.state.startDate  }
     />
}
```

**ReservationCalendar.js**

```
const ReservationCalendar = ({dateFormat, startDate}) => (
    <Calendar
        dateFormat={ dateFormat }
        startDate={ startDate }/>
);

export default ReservationCalendar;
```

**DatePicker.js**

```
const Calendar = ({dateFormat, startDate}) => (
    <div className="my-calendar">
        <DatePicker
            inline
            dateFormat={ dateFormat }
            selected={ startDate }
        />
    </div>
);

export default Calendar;
```

With everything like that, I'm still getting a view like i've attached. Maybe I'm not passing something through correctly. Thank you again for your time!

[image]

Answer (score 31):

Needed something similar at work recently. This is how I was able to do it using `formatWeekDay` prop:

```
<DatePicker
  formatWeekDay={nameOfDay => nameOfDay.substr(0,3)}
/>;
```

[image: calendar screenshot]

Note: Couldn't find this prop in public facing docs though.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **useWeekdaysShort** attribute of react-datepicker.

e.g:

```html
<DatePicker>
  useWeekdaysShort={true}
</DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use:

`dateFormat={"EEEE"}`

Or:

`dateFormat={"EEE"}`

Comment: Why is this not the top answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prop called `dateFormat` to format the date to your desired output. To get the days as `Sun Mon Tue`, pass `dateFormat="ddd"` as a props to the component. Like this way

```
<DatePicker
dateFormat="ddd"
onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've updated my question to show how I'm passing in the properties. I've tried adding `dateFormat` but no luck. Maybe I'm not passing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The DayPicker allows you to pass custom elements for the days of the week using the `weekdayElement` prop. Thus, you could create a `Weekday` element, translate the name to the long name using the `formatWeekdayLong` method from react-day-picker utils, and cut that name down to a string of 3 characters. Something like the following worked for me:

```
const Weekday = ({ weekday, className, localeUtils, locale }) => {
    const longWeekday = localeUtils.formatWeekdayLong(weekday, locale);
    const newWeekday = longWeekday.substring(0,3);

    return <div className={className}>{newWeekday}</div>;
};


// Date Picker Component
const InputDatePicker = () => {
  return (
    <div className='input-date-picker__container'>
      <DayPicker
        weekdayElement={<Weekday />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you look at the `localeUtils` parameter passed to the `Weekday` component you will see there are a lot of handy methods passed there.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you can use the prop `formatWeekDay`. Pass a function that should be used to format the week day and everything will work correctly!

```js
<DatePicker
  formatWeekDay={(day: string) => day.substr(0,3)}
/>;
```